pip install from private repo via GitHub Actions workflow
TL;DR: How do you pass GITHUB_TOKEN to pip in callable workflow? Any additional setup required?
I'm trying to write a set of workflows that installs dependencies located on a private GitHub repo.
The repos with packages have "Access from repositories in the 'My Org' organization" enabled.
GITHUB_TOKEN has write permissions set by default.
In project's action the workflow is called with GITHUB_TOKEN passed explicitly:
.github/workflows/deploy_myproject.yaml:
name: Deploy "My Project" to Sandbox
run-name:  Deploying to sbx
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - sandbox
    paths:
      - 'my_project/**'
      - .github/workflows/deploy_myproject.yaml

jobs:
  deploy:
    uses: MyORG/github-actions/.github/workflows/call_pip_install.yaml@main
    secrets:
      GH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
    with:
      env_name: sandbox


MyORG/github-actions/.github/workflows/call_pip_install.yaml:
name: Deploy PIP
run-name:  Deploying to ${{ inputs.env_name }}

on:
  workflow_call:
  
    inputs:
      env_name:
        description: 'Target environment'
        required: true
        type: string
        default: "sandbox"

    secrets:
      GH_TOKEN:
        description: 'A token passed from the caller workflow'
        required: true

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Python 3.12
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: 3.12
      - name: 'Set up Python & deploy'
        run:  |
          python3 -m venv venv
          source ./venv/bin/activate

          echo "Installing dependencies"

          git config --global url."https://${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}@github".insteadOf https://github
          git config --list
          ./venv/bin/pip3 install -r requirements.txt -v

git config --list is just to confirm there's url.https://***@github.insteadof=https://github
requirements.txt:
module-1 @ git+https://github.com/MyORG/module-1-repo@main
module-2 @ git+https://github.com/MyORG/module-2-repo@main

I tired also with {{ github.token }} inside call_pip_install.yaml since that's just meta annotation that should be accessible across workflows, but ended up explicitly passing token just to be sure.
In both cases the workflow fails with:
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://***@github.com': No such device or address

The same configuration works if I inject personal token instead of GITHUB_TOKEN.
After researching many other posts on SO I've also tried these formats of requirements.txt instead of global git config:
module-1 @ git+https://x-access-token:{GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/MyORG/module-1-repo@main
module-1 @ git+https://oauth2:{GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/MyORG/module-1-repo@main

but they fail with remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. or similar errors
I don't want to use SSH keys or pass PAT to workflow since these are long-living secrets, I want to use GITHUB_TOKEN because it's disposable

It's confirmed to be a limit on GitHub side and a feature where GITHUB_TOKEN could allow access other repos within the org is not gonna happen this year: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/46566#discussioncomment-10865317
The only solutions are (in descending order of implementation simplicity):

PAT as Org-wide secret that's accessible from all org workflows by default
PAT as a per-repo workflow secret
SSH key secret
GitHub App token

I suggest to use Fine-grained tokens (beta) because they allow limit access to particular repos:

Go to https://github.com/settings/tokens?type=beta
Generate new token
Select repos it needs an access to and what kind of accesses

Please note that Fine-grained tokens manage access only to repos you own. For repos inside organization corresponding policies have to be configured first:
https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-programmatic-access-to-your-organization/setting-a-personal-access-token-policy-for-your-organization
I would discourage people from using using classic Personal Access Tokens because this will grant access to all repositories within the organizations that you have access to, as well as all personal repositories in your personal account.
Another alternative is GitHub App, but it requires considerably more complex setup:
https://docs.github.com/en/apps/using-github-apps/installing-your-own-github-app
https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/authenticating-as-a-github-app-installation
